# Upload file and JSON to PostMan

Tags: json, angular, postman, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I've tried many SO answers and none work in my case to upload a file and some JSON since my JSON is a collection.

My .Net Core 3.1 Web Api controller action takes a single argument of type `FileUpload`, which looks like this:

```cs
    public class FileUpload
    {
        public IFormFile FileData { get; set; }
        public List<ImageOption> ImageOptions { get; set; } = new List<ImageOption>();
    }

    public class ImageOption
    {
        public int? Width { get; set; }
        public InterpolationMode Quality { get; set; } = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    }
```

The controller action looks like this:

```cs
    [HttpPost("uploadfile")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(FileUpload file)
    {
        ...
    }
```

When `FileUpload` is serialized as JSON it looks like this:

```json
{
  "FileData": null,
  "ImageOptions": [
    {
      "Width": 400,
      "Quality": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

When I Post to PostMan, I only get the file back (which is good) but not the `ImageOptions`.  The `ImageOptions` collection is always empty.

This is one attempt in PostMan to get this to work.

[image]

I also tried this:

[image]

Still the `ImageOptions` collection is empty.

[image]

Is this possible to do? What am I missing? The request will be made from an Angular app, so I need to know how to build the request correctly from Angular so my .Net project can consume it.

How do I post to PostMan?

What does the request look like from Angular?  I'm trying to test passing the array in Swagger with no success.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out the answer to one of my questions, which was how to post an array to PostMan, and this is my solution:

[image]

But now I need to know how to send the request from Angular to the Web Api with both the file and the additional data as an array.

Any suggestions is appreciated.